# Cannot remove on collection items. (using CollectionType, OneToMany bidirectional)

Tags: php, symfony, collections, doctrine

I have a question about collection persistence in Symfony2.8.10 and Doctrine.
I wrote following entity classes, Article and ArticleAttribute.

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticleRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * */
class Article
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var ArticleAttribute[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleAttribute", mappedBy="article", cascade={"ALL"})
     */
    private $attributes;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->attributes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get attributes
     *
     * @return ArticleAttribute[]
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    /**
     * @param $item ArticleAttribute
     */
    public function addAttribute($item)
    {
        $this->attributes[$item->getAttribute()] = $item;
        $item->setArticle($this);
    }

    /**
     * Remove attributes
     *
     * @param ArticleAttribute $attribute
     */
    public function removeAttribute(ArticleAttribute $attribute)
    {
        $this->attributes->removeElement($attribute);
    }
...

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="article_attribute")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArticleAttribute
{
    /**
     * @var Article
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="attributes")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $attribute;

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return Article
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param Article $article
     * @return ArticleAttribute
     */
    public function setArticle(Article $article)
    {
        $this->article = $article;
        return $this;
    }
....
```

Bound to form these classes.

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id')
            ->add('title')
            ->add('attributes', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => ArticleAttributeType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
            ]);
    }
```

above code is part of FormType.

Remove several ArticleAttributes on page.
Submit form.
call handleRequest and $em->flush();
But removed items still remain on database.

I found a workaround for this issue.
I modified onSubmit method in FormResizeListener class.

```
    public function onSubmit(FormEvent $event)
    {
        /** @var FormBuilder $form */
        $form = $event->getForm();
        /** @var PersistentCollection $data */
        $data = $event->getData();

        // At this point, $data is an array or an array-like object that already contains the
        // new entries, which were added by the data mapper. The data mapper ignores existing
        // entries, so we need to manually unset removed entries in the collection.

        if (null === $data) {
            $data = [];
        }

        if (!is_array($data) && !($data instanceof \Traversable && $data instanceof \ArrayAccess)) {
            throw new UnexpectedTypeException($data, 'array or (\Traversable and \ArrayAccess)');
        }

        if ($this->deleteEmpty) {
            $previousData = $event->getForm()->getData();
            foreach ($form as $name => $child) {
                $isNew = !isset($previousData[$name]);

                // $isNew can only be true if allowAdd is true, so we don't
                // need to check allowAdd again
                if ($child->isEmpty() && ($isNew || $this->allowDelete)) {
                    unset($data[$name]);
                    $form->remove($name);
                }
            }
        }

        // The data mapper only adds, but does not remove items, so do this
        // here
        if ($this->allowDelete) {
            $arr = (array)$data; //added
            /** @var EntityManager $em */ //added
            $em = @$arr["\0Doctrine\\ORM\\PersistentCollection\0em"]; //added

            $toDelete = [];

            foreach ($data as $name => $child) {
                if (!$form->has($name)) {
                    $toDelete[] = $name;
                }
            }

            foreach ($toDelete as $name) {
                if ($em) $em->remove($data[$name]); //added
                unset($data[$name]);
            }
        }

        $event->setData($data);
    }
```

By Calling $em->remove, register deletion of removed items to unit of work.

After modified. removed items are deleted from database correctly.
But I think this is nasty.
Please tell me correct way to avoid this issue.
I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify `Article` relation with `ArticleAttributes` adding `orphanRemoval` option

```
/**
 * @var ArticleAttribute[]
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleAttribute", mappedBy="article", cascade={"ALL"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $attributes;
```

I also suggest to read [this article](https://labs.madisoft.it/orphan-removal-forms-collection-and-collections-elements-swapping-pick-your-poison/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tried to add orphanRemoval option.
It works fine!
Straightforward way.
I was able to come out from the labyrinth with your help.

Comment: @Miwanoushi: please read also external reference I've linked because it's important to know how that works in deep. Moreover, if this is the right answer, please check it with the “green mark“. Thank you.

Comment: I read the page you've linked. It is helpful for me. Especially use case of "change owner". I understand how that works.
I'll set orphanRemoval to true almost case of parent - children relationship in my project. Thank you, DonCallisto.